# Converting Lat,Long to XY in ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: coordinates, arcgis-python-api

I am working on a Alexa skill where I get the user's location (`Lat, Long`) from the device. Since my skill only applies to a specific city (Boston, USA), I am using the ArcGIS `reverse_geocode` to determine if that Lat, Long is in Boston, but the input is in the XY format.

I wrote the following method:

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geocoding import reverse_geocode
from arcgis.geometry import from_geo_coordinate_string

gis = GIS()
location = [42.3937647, -71.1449038]
m_location = reverse_geocode(location)
print(m_location)

# Error:
# Cannot perform query. Invalid query parameters.
# Unable to find address for the specified location.
```

Therefore, I need to convert my lat,long to XY. I found the [find_transformation](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.geometry.html#find-transformation) function, but don't know how to use as inputs (the in_sr and out_sr, for instance).

I cannot use packages such as `pyproj`, because the team does not approve, and I'm positive that ArcGIS has a function for converting between coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation found here https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/reverse-geocoding/,

> `Location` parameter
>
> The point from which to search for the closest address. The point can
>   be represented as a simple list of coordinates ([x, y] or [longitude,
>   latitude]) or as a JSON point object.

reverse the order of the location. Either:

- `m_location = reverse_geocode([location[1], location[0]])`
- or simply change location to have longitude listed first, like `location = [-71..., 42...]` (obscured for privacy reasons).

This will use the default spatial reference of WGS84, but can be overridden if needed. Your geocode is likely to be in WGS84.

Comment: Perfect! I had my location in Lat, Long, but the function takes Long, Lat